# React native node modules: how to keep changes in Android modules in git?

Tags: git, react-native, node-modules, gitignore

I have a React native project which requires to change some code inside the Android project of some library. The problem is that the library is positioned inside the node_modules folder and it's not been saved when pushing to get, because node_modules is ignored. I know I can remove node_modules from .gitignore but I think there should me another way, some better practice?

Comment: You could fork the project and do your changes, but there may be some better practice someone knows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way is that customize your module and use it from another address! for example I written many module and saved them like this :

```
   ./rootOfProject


        ./node_modules 

        ./custom_modules <-- here!
```

**Note :**
In your android folder you need some changes! for example,

from :

```
project(':react-native-someModules').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-onesignal/android')
```

to :

```
project(':react-native-someModules').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../custom_modules/react-native-alarm-manager/android')
```

But why is this common solution?

Usually `node_modules` size is very large and it's not good to upload this to git or copy paste from a system to another, and for solve this problem, npm save module name's in `package.json` and everywhere that you want can run `npm i` and get node_modules!

Comment: the problem is that android studio cannot find the modules in that case :
Unable to find module with Gradle path ':react-native-spinkit'

Comment: and what about ios ??