# How to display the name of who chatted me in react native gifted chat

Tags: react-native, react-native-gifted-chat

[image]It looks like this is my backend for the chat messaging app any idea of this problem? I wanted to display the name of who chatted me

```
 loadMessages(callback) {
    this.messagesRef = firebase.database().ref("messages");
    this.messagesRef.off();
    const onReceive = data => {
      const message = data.val();
      callback({
        id: data.key,
        text: message.text,
        createdAt: message.createdAt,
        user: {
          _id: message.user._id,
          name: message.user.Uemail,
        }
      });
    };
```

Comment: Wondered this myself as well. Haven't seen a clear explanation.

Comment: this one I cant see who chatted me

Answer (score 4):

You can use **renderUsernameOnMessage** props for this.

> **Doc** : renderUsernameOnMessage (Bool) - Indicate whether to show the user's
>   username inside the message bubble; default is false

In other hand you can customize this component and change whatever you want! 
maybe related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51796951/react-native-node-modules-how-to-keep-changes-in-android-modules-in-git/51797164#51797164)

Comment: like this : `<GiftedChat  renderUsernameOnMessage={true} {...otherProps} />`

Comment: I already did this last time but nothing happens this is my code

Comment: <GiftedChat
        
        renderUsernameOnMessage={true}
          messages={this.state.messages}
          onSend={message => {
            Backend.sendMessage(message);
          }}
          user={{
            _id: Backend.getUid(),
            name: Backend.getUemail()
          }}
        />

Answer (score 0):

you nee to pass props `renderUsernameOnMessage={true}` and pass name inside user

in my case

```
  <GiftedChat
                messages={messages}
                onSend={messages => onSend(messages)}
                renderAvatar={null}            // remove avtar
                renderUsernameOnMessage={true} // default is false
               user={{
                    _id: userId,
                    name:name                  // display name
                }}
            />
```